# Stop image from shifting when opening button

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want the image to stop shifting down whenever I open my button. I tried changing the position of the image to fixed but then the image disappears from my page and I'm not sure where it goes. Any advice on how to solve this would be much appreciated.

```css
.image3 {
  position: fixed;
}

.collapsible {
  background-color: #C5E3ED;
  color: black;
  padding: 15px;
  width: 400px;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family:apple chancery;
  border:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  border-radius:5px;
}

.active, .collapsible:hover {
  background-color: #8bc7db;
}

.content {
  padding: 0 18px;
  max-height: 0;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: scroll;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
  background-color: #C5E3ED;
  width: 365px;
}

<script>
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var content = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (content.style.maxHeight){
      content.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
    } 
  });
}
</script>
```

```html
  <button class="collapsible">title</button>
  <div class="content">
    <p>text</p>
  </div>
<img src="https://www.w3schools.com/Bootstrap/paris.jpg" alt="wolf" class="image3">
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with your JavaScript; you're apply massive margins in your CSS. You're applying a `margin-left` of `-478px`, so your image gets shifted `478px` off the screen. Considering it's only 400 pixels wide, it gets hidden entirely out of view. Use smaller values, or percentage-based margins if you have to.

Comment: I have my image working, the problem is not that I cannot see my image because I can see it on where I'm working with it. My issues is that it moves.

Answer (score 1):

Try `position:fixed` instead of `display:fixed`. `display:fixed` does not exist. display has options like block, inline, none, inline-block, etc.

Also, if you're using margins like that you're probably not coding it the right way. I would research using auto margins and float if you want it to be an inline element.

EDIT: Saw your comment and since you want a temporary solution, you can move the button up when it is clicked.

```
button:hover:active { margin-top:-5px; }
```

Comment: I accidentally put display instead of position but position does not work.

Comment: @Silk I would rewrite the CSS because your use of margins is not right but if you want to just fix the problem use :hover and :active in your css and add margin-top:-2px or however many pixels your image is moving down

Comment: I will defiantly look into margins more now that I know I'm doing it wrong. Thank you

Comment: @Silk No problem! Using percentages and viewport units as well as grid and flexbox are all very important design components to learn about. However, they can definitely get confusing, so have patience with yourself! I also edited my answer, so see if that can help you

Answer (score 0):

where do you want to display your image?I can see a button and a content div size(300*365) and below that you have your image.

Don't set any any margin for your image and it will come up.

Comment: My image display is underneath my button and it's working great. The image showing up is not my problem. It's the fact that my image is moving when I open the button.

Comment: Do you want to overlay  your content over the image when your button expands?if so , You can use the below https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-position.asp

Comment: I think so yes. When my button expands, I just don't want my image moving with the button. so yes, the button information would be over the image if that makes sense?

Comment: Answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12360973/need-to-fix-an-image-to-a-specific-spot-on-a-page